# Simulation environment for conducting visual servoing experiment

Tags: software, simulation, visual-servoing

I want to conduct the following experiment:
I want to set up a scene with a kuka lwr4+ arm, a 3D model of an object and a camera overlooking them. I want to find the pose of the object using some pose estimation algorithm and move the arm towards the object. 
In general I want a piece of software or a combination of cooperating software that can do all that without having to reinvent the wheel. Is there anything available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider taking a look at [Gazebo Robotic Simulation](http://gazebosim.org/) and the [Robot Operating System](http://www.ros.org/). Both might require a bunch of work getting used to, but I am sure it is worth the effort.

Comment: I did a little research and Gazebo and V-Rep were the most interesting tools that came up. Have you any idea if the simulation/experiment I described can be conducted in both of them?

Comment: I don't know anything about V-Rep, but from what I have seen in the documentation, Gazebo could really be the way to go.

Comment: I have some experience in V-REP it's also possible to do what you describe, you can choose to use ROS or not.